# C++ member function pointer to global function pointer

Tags: c++, delphi, delegates, pointer-to-member

I have to solve, at least for me, a tricky problem in C++. There is a dll which i can not modify. It gets a function pointer as argument. If I pass a pointer to a global function everything works fine. Unfortunatelly there is a **list of same class objects to pass to the dll**. In C# I solved this by using delegates. How can this be done in C++? Using std::function does not work. With that there are coding convention errors during runtime. Further using MSVC2010 would be optimal.
I wrote a sample which describes the problem:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>


// global function which works
void __stdcall task_global(float x, float y) { printf("Called global function with: %f %f\n", x, y); }
typedef void(__stdcall *f_pointer)(float, float);



// try of using a member function
class BaseTask {
public:
    virtual void __stdcall task(float x, float y) = 0;
};


class ListeningTask :public BaseTask {
public:
    void __stdcall task(float x, float y) { printf("Called this member function with: %f %f\n", x, y); }
};

typedef void (BaseTask::*member_f_pointer)(float, float);



// the dll to use
class RegisterTask {
public:
    // no posibility to access or modify!
    void __stdcall subscribe(f_pointer fp) { fp(1.0f, 2.0f); }
    // just for demonstration how to use a member function pointer
    void __stdcall subscribeMemberDemo(member_f_pointer mfp) {  /*how to use mfp?*/};
};



int main() {

    RegisterTask register_task{};

    // use global function
    f_pointer pointer_to_global_task = task_global;
    register_task.subscribe(pointer_to_global_task);


    /*---------------------------------------------------------------*/
    // use member function?
    std::list<ListeningTask> listening_task_list;
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        listening_task_list.push_back(ListeningTask lt);
        member_f_pointer pointer_to_member_task = &listening_task_list.back().task; //error C2276: '&': illegal operation on bound member function expression
        register_task.subscribeMemberDemo(pointer_to_member_task);

        // the tricky and important one to solve
        // how to pass the member function to this subscribe(f_pointer)?
        register_task.subscribe(pointer_to_member_task);
    }

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

The important question is how to pass a member function pointer to the `RegisterTask::subscribe(f_pointer)`?

The parenthetic question is how to pass a member function to the `RegisterTask::subscribeMemberDemo(member_f_pointer)`?

I hope someone can help me to solve this? I am working on this since days.

**Edit:**
I modified the question to emphasize the problem with the **list of `ListenerTask`**. How to pass a member function pointer is now clear to me through the answers of @pokey909 and @AndyG. Both of them provide a pointer to one object or rather a list of objects. If the callback is called the one `ListenerTask` or all `std::list<*ListenerTask>` are called at once. But how to let only one `ListenerTask` of the list to be called. *Passing more than one callback to the dll. It (`RegisterTask`) can do that, because the following example with global functions works.*

```
void __stdcall task_global_1(float x, float y) { printf("Called global function 1 with: %f %f\n", x, y); }
void __stdcall task_global_2(float x, float y) { printf("Called global function 2 with: %f %f\n", x, y); }
void __stdcall task_global_3(float x, float y) { printf("Called global function 3 with: %f %f\n", x, y); }

typedef void(__stdcall *f_pointer)(float, float);

int main() {
    // give the functions to the dll.
    f_pointer pointer_to_global_task_1 = task_global_1;
    register_task.subscribe(pointer_to_global_task_1);

    f_pointer pointer_to_global_task_2 = task_global_2;
    register_task.subscribe(pointer_to_global_task_2);

    f_pointer pointer_to_global_task_3 = task_global_3;
    register_task.subscribe(pointer_to_global_task_3);
}
```

There are three global function pointers. They are all given to the dll. Now, if the dll has a task for `task_global_2` it notifies this only! How to achive this distinction with member function pointer?

**Note:**
I got the **source of the dll**. Hope this helps. Unfortunately modifying, building is not possible. Here is the *callback definition*:

```
type TCallback = procedure( x : single; y : single; ); stdcall;

procedure subscribe(aCallback: TCallback ); StdCall;
begin
  TaskSocket.addTask( aCallback );
end;

procedure TSocket.addTask( aCallback : TCallback);
var newTask : TTask;
begin
  newTask := TTask.Create(aCallback);
  TaskList.addItem(newTask);
end;
```

Comment: Without any C++11 features, this will be surprisingly difficult for you. Basically you'll want to implement a form a `std::bind`

Comment: You can't. The hidden `this` parameter gets you. Instead pass a static method that calls the method you want to execute into the dll. You will have to find some way of knowing which object to invoke in the static method. If you only have one instance of the object this will be easy. If not...

Comment: Why isn't `RegisterTask::subscribe` declared static? It doesn't use `this`.

Comment: You have abstracted away details about the callback function pointer I suspect.  Please provide the exact signature if you have not already.  Not what you think is importsnt, the exact signature of the function pointer passed in.  And the function that accepts it.  (Minimizing is good, but hard!)

Comment: Yakk has a great point. Often callback registrations take a `void *` that will be used as a parameter to the callback function so that multiple receivers can be multiplexed. That quickly solves the "Which object should I invoke?" problem.

Comment: @Barmar I have not much details yet about the class `RegisterTask` I have the dll only.

Comment: @solarisx Never mind, I misunderstood which function you were trying to pass. I thought you were trying to turn `subscribe` into a function pointer, not pass a function pointer as an argument to it.

Comment: @Yakk Based on what he posted, the callback function is just expected to take two `float` arguments. So there's no `void *` argument that can hold a pointer to the object.

Comment: @Yakk You mean, if it is possible to pass a `void(*)(float,float)` to `subscribe`? I think it is. Currently I am out of office, so I will test it tomorrow. How to use it with `void(*)(float, float)`?

Comment: @solarisx He was suggesting that the signature might be `void (*f)(void*, float, float)`, where the `void*` argument is an opaque pointer to be used by the callback function.

Comment: @Barmar I think there must be an opaque pointer. Because I can use this dll in C# with delegates like `public delegate void TaskDelegate(float x, float y);` which are pointing to objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a freestanding function that calls a wrapper which binds your instance to it.
Here is rough example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <functional>

// global function which works
std::function<void(float, float)> memberCb;
void task_global(float x, float y) { memberCb(x, y); }
typedef void(*f_pointer)(float, float);


// try of using a member function
class BaseTask {
public:
    virtual void  task(float x, float y) = 0;
};


class ListeningTask :public BaseTask {
public:
    void  task(float x, float y) { printf("Called this member function with: %f %f\n", x, y); }
};

typedef void (BaseTask::*member_f_pointer)(float, float);

void callbackWrapper(BaseTask* t, float x, float y) { t->task(x, y); }

// the dll to use
class RegisterTask {
public:
    // no posibility to access or modify!
    void  subscribe(f_pointer fp) { 
        fp(1.0f, 2.0f); 
    }
    // just for demonstration how to use a member function pointer
    void  subscribeMemberDemo(member_f_pointer mfp) {  /*???*/ };
};



int main() {

    RegisterTask register_task{};

    ListeningTask listening_task{};
    memberCb = std::bind(&callbackWrapper, &listening_task, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2);
    register_task.subscribe(task_global);

    return 0;
}
```

**Note**

Based on the comment, I'm not sure if all of this works in MSVC2010, since I don't have this compiler version. But rudimentary C++11 support should be in there.

**Edit**

I'm not sure if thats what you are after, but would this solve your problem?

```
void callbackWrapper(const std::list<BaseTask*> &taskList, float x, float y) {
    for (auto t : taskList)
        t->task(x, y); 
}

int main() {

    RegisterTask register_task{};

    std::list<BaseTask*> taskList;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
        taskList.push_back(new ListeningTask);
    memberCb = std::bind(&callbackWrapper, taskList, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2);
    register_task.subscribe(task_global);

    return 0;
}
```

**Edit 2**
Ok I think I got what you want. The best I can come up with without splattering your code with global functions manually is with template magic.
Note however, that it is not as flexible as you might want because you have to bind those methods at compile time.
If you need to add them at runtime, you can probably use the same trick but without templates. Simply put all the std::function objects in a vector and wrap that up in a singleton or something similar.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <functional>
#include <list>


/* Simulated DLL */
typedef void(*f_pointer)(float, float);
class RegisterTask {
public:
    void  subscribe(f_pointer fp) {
        fp(1.0f, 2.0f);
    }
};



/* Static function generator to ease the pain to define all of them manually */
template<unsigned int T>
std::function<void(float, float)> &getWrapper() {
    static std::function<void(float, float)> fnc;
    return fnc;
}

/* Same here */
template<unsigned int T>
void task_global(float x, float y) { getWrapper<T>()(x, y); }



class BaseTask {
public:
    virtual void  task(float x, float y) = 0;
};
class ListeningTask :public BaseTask {
public:
    ListeningTask(int taskNum) : m_taskNum(taskNum) {}
    void  task(float x, float y) { printf("Called this member of task %d function with: %f %f\n", getTaskNum(), x, y); }
    int getTaskNum() const { return m_taskNum; }
private:
    int m_taskNum;
};


/* Context injector */
void callbackWrapper(BaseTask* t, float x, float y) {
    t->task(x, y);
}

/* Convenience function to bind an instance to a task */
template<unsigned int T>
void bindTask(ListeningTask* t) {
    getWrapper<T>() = std::bind(&callbackWrapper, t, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2);
}

int main() {

    RegisterTask register_task{};

    auto task0 = new ListeningTask(1337);
    auto task1 = new ListeningTask(1984);
    auto task2 = new ListeningTask(42);

    bindTask<0>(task0);
    register_task.subscribe(task_global<0>);

    bindTask<1>(task1);
    register_task.subscribe(task_global<1>);

    bindTask<2>(task2);
    register_task.subscribe(task_global<2>);

    return 0;
}
```

[**Run Code demo**](http://cpp.sh/9boz)

Comment: I thought he said he's using a C++ version that predates `std::bind`.

Comment: @Barmar `std::function` and `std::bind` are in Visual Studio 2010. Not sure how well they work since VS2010 targets an as-yet unstandardized standard, but they're in there. The compiler will trip over `RegisterTask register_task{};`, but that's an easy fix.

Comment: In VS2010 `bind` is in the tr1 namespace (`tr1::bind`).

Comment: thanks for the reminder. I actually thought he can use C++11 since he used C++11 style initialization. But I updated my answer just for the records.

Comment: Just tested. Compiles and runs. Just lose the `{}` on the variable declarations.

Comment: @pokey909 Thank this works great. But it does not solve my problem entirety using a list of Tasks. As `memberCb` and `task_global` are global, I can bind only on Task object to them. How can I do this with a `std::list<ListenerTask>`?

Comment: Can you use lambdas?

Comment: @pokey909 If lambdas are the only way to solve this, then I will try to use a newer compiler than MSVC 2010.

Comment: @pokey909 No, this uses one callback to a list. I need one callback to each list entry. I extended the description of my question. Would  be glad if you could have a look again on it.

Comment: @pokey909 Thanks again for your extensive help! I dont know the number of `ListenerTask` at compile-time and your code does not work with a dynamic number. It is funny that this problem seems not solveable in C++, but is easily done with delegates in C#.

Comment: It is. As I said in the last paragraph "If you need to add them at runtime, you can probably use the same trick but without templates. Simply put all the std::function objects in a vector and wrap that up in a singleton"

Answer (score 2):

[pokey909's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39582503/27678) is totally great, but if you don't even have access to `std::function` and `std::bind`, we can hack our way around it.

The gist of the approach is that we are going to define a template class with an implicit conversion to the desired function type. The downside is that each new additional wrapper requires a new type declaration.

```
// assumes two function arguments
template<class Ret, class Mem, class Arg1, class Arg2, int>
struct MemBind
{
    typedef Ret(Mem::*mem_fn_type)(Arg1, Arg2);
    static void Set(mem_fn_type _fn, Mem* _instance)
    {
        fn = _fn;
        instance = _instance;
    }

    static Ret DoTheThing(Arg1 first, Arg2 second)
    {
        return ((*instance).*fn)(first, second);
    }

    typedef Ret(*fn_type)(Arg1, Arg2); 
    operator fn_type ()
    {
        return DoTheThing;
    }

    static mem_fn_type fn;
    static Mem* instance;
};
```

Given some struct `Foo` with our desired callback:

```
struct Foo
{
    void Bar(float a, float b)
    {
        std::cout << "Foo::Bar(float, float) " << a << " , " << b << std::endl;
    }
};
```

We have to define our static members:

```
typedef MemBind<void, Foo, float, float, 0> MemBindZero;
template<> Foo* MemBindZero::instance = nullptr;
template<>  void(Foo::*MemBindZero::fn)(float, float)  = nullptr;
```

We can have a caller that takes in a function pointer:

```
void Caller(void(*_fn)(float, float))
{
    _fn(42.0, 1337.0);
}
```

The key here is that `MemBind` has an implicit conversion to the desired function type. The `0` in the typedef for `MemBindZero` allows us to re-use the same types for the other arguments, but increment the counter to `1` when used. I think you could probably replace it with a `__COUNTER__` macro or something like that, but it would be nonstandard so I did it manually.

Now the next bit is to create an instance of `MemBindZero`, then set the `static` members, and finally pass our instance into `Caller`:

```
 Foo f;
 MemBindZero bound;
 bound.Set(&Foo::Bar, &f);
 Caller(bound);
```

### Demo

---

In the demo I wrapped the static member initialization into a more convenient macro:

```
#define MEMBIND(RET, CLASS, ARG1, ARG2, COUNT, ALIAS) \
typedef MemBind<RET, CLASS, ARG1, ARG2, COUNT> ALIAS; \
template<> CLASS * ALIAS::instance = nullptr; \
template<>  RET(CLASS::*ALIAS::fn)(ARG1, ARG2)  = nullptr;
```

So that I could call it like so:

```
MEMBIND(void, Foo, float, float, 0, MemBindZero)
MEMBIND(void, OtherFoo, float, float, 1, MemBindOne)
```

Comment: I'm totally overcomplicating things here, I know. This is mostly me playing around with templates.

Comment: Thanks very much! This works for one callback. How can I use a `std::list<Foo>` and link a callback to each on of its entries? I extended my question to descripe this point more clearly. Maybe you can have a look on it?

Comment: I don't totally understand your edit. Do you want to disable some callbacks? Or it sounds like you're asking how to make the subscribee only call one of the callbacks?

Comment: I want one callback to each `ListenerTask` I pass to the dll through `subscribe()`. Like in my global example, if the dll has something to do for `task_global_2`, it notifies this one only. I need to pass a non-static member function for each object to the dll. So the dll can distinguish  between the passed function pointers. What else of information can I provide?

Comment: @solarisx: How is the DLL distinguishing between callbacks right now? You mentioned that you cannot modify it, so we're stuck with whatever logic it's using.

Comment: The DLL gets unique/different function pointers and stores them. I would be easy if an ID could be passed to the DLL and then the DLL calls back with this ID included, but isnt.